# Assemblers Used During the Development of a Programming Language?

Tags: programming-languages, assembly

I am currently designing and developing a programming language from scratch. Mostly as a learning experience. *Although it's not entirely related to the question, it's important that you know a little bit of the backstory*.

I have a fairly good idea as to how I'll turn the code from my language into the target assembly code, but there is a slight problem: which assemblers does one normally use when developing and creating a programming language (as for code generation)?

For Windows, I could theoretically compile my language into the *MASM* syntax, but then that wouldn't be available on all target Windows machines using my programming language. And I believe (don't take my word for it) I read somewhere that you're not allowed to bundle it up with your own software and redistribute it.

I suppose one could use *NASM*, as that would work on Linux and has the potential of working on Windows as well. But I feel as though there has to be another way. Surely people haven't relied on standalone software to compile their programs in the past?

**Is there some architecture specific assembler bundled up with the operating system you are on, or do you need to rely on such aforementioned software?**

*I'm sure one could just compile down to ones and zeroes with no intermediate assembly language step, but that sounds a slight bit tedious, don't you think? ;-)*

Comment: Would someone care to explain what my question lacks, so I can make sure not to repeat the same error when I reask this question at a later date?

Comment: Have you considered generating C?

Comment: While you could certainly use assembly as your compilation target, why not just output the actual opcodes if you already know what they are?  As @ErikEidt points out, you could generate C instead of assembly and that would compile on any platform that supports C.  Or you could use a backend like LLVM.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm looking for a hands on experience in terms of compiler development. That is, I want my program to be able to compile down to assembly language, to then be assembled and linked.

To build upon my question: what assembler would normally be preferable? Is it one of those things the language developer gets to choose on their own, as long as the assembler's license allows for redistribution, so that it can be shipped alongside the compiler?

Comment: Any decent assembler ought to suffice.  Try to find one with syntax you like.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_assemblers

Comment: https://flatassembler.net/download.php

Comment: @D.Ataro, why do you want to compile down to assembly if there are no other compiler being developed that work that way?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Actually most compilers (at least back in the day) do just this, as it's easier to debug the assembly output than something that will be displayed as hexadecimal or octal values. Anything modern compiler using LLVM would be the exception, as described in amon's answer.

Comment: You need to provide some context for your question to narrow it down. The way that it now reads, the answer is something like: "Almost any assembly language could be used for your purposes." I believe that the gist of your question is: Which solution do you use when...[state the context.]"

Answer (score 5):

Most compilers bundle an assembler and linker as part of their backend. These may or may not be standalone programs. For example, LLVM will not generate textual assembly language, but generates machine code directly from the in-memory IR (intermediate representation). Using LLVM as a library in your compiler is the easiest way to get a production-grade native compiler backend.

Note that many programming languages are not implemented as compilers but as interpreters, as interpreters are generally much easier to develop. E.g. you might get garbage collection “for free” from the host language, without having to develop a language runtime in addition to the compiler.